# How many times solar eclipse have occured during mahabharata war?

Tags: mahabharata, eclipse

I heard from the scriptures that solar eclipse happened 3 times during the same paksha (sukla quarter) it signifies total destruction and Yuga change. Wants to know the scriptural reference for the same.

In the same month quite often we are getting 2 to 3 eclipse. but not in the same paksha(Quarter).

Comment: Solar eclipse can happen only on a new moon day (amAvAsya). It is not possible for more than one in a paksha.

Comment: then the war started on Amavasya(according to Duryodhana) but on padya (according to Krishna) … when it jayadratha got killed sure that there was one solar eclipse during his killing..

Comment: @PrasannaR During Jayadratha's killing, Sri Krishna covered the Dun by Sudarshana Chakra.So how it cd be eclipse?